Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G.$
This question was asked in my mock test of masters entrance test and I couldn't prove one of the question:

Question $\to$ Let $G$ be a group of order $105$ and $H$ be it's subgroup of order $35$. Then show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G ,$ $H$ is cyclic$, $ and $H$  has a normal subgroup of $K$ of order $5$ and $K$  is normal in $G$.

Using Sylow theorems I proved that $H$  is cyclic and $H$ has a normal subgroup of $K$ of order $5$ and $K$ is normal in $G.$ But I am not able to show that $H$  must be normal
Can you please help me with that?
I am following contemporary abstract algebra by Joseph Gallian.

Two subgroups of order 35, say H and H', would intersect in a subgroup of order at most 7, and hence HH' would have size at least 175. Contradiction.

Alternatively, the index of $H$ is the smallest prime that divides $|G|$.

See also this post.

Consider the action of $G$ in $G/H$ (note that it isn't necessary a group) by translation, $x.(gH)=(xg)H$. We know $\#G/H=3$, then we have a morphism from $G$ to $Biy(G/H)\cong S_3$ by $x\mapsto \varphi_x$ where $\varphi_x:G/H\longrightarrow G/H$, $gH\mapsto x.gH$ is a biyection. If you prove that the kernel of the morphism is $H$ we will finish.
Hint: Use that $3$ is less that $5$ and $7$.
